# How to calculate water vapor budget for a selected region in GRADS or MAT Lab

Tags: meteorology, climatology, reanalysis

I need to calculate water vapor budget for a selected region. Can anyone suggest a specific link or code for the above mentioned tools please. I have seen a link for NCL but i am not familiar with that tool. 
Regards